# Q: Viewer Performance Issues?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there something going on with the viewer? We're getting very poor performance with how it’s rendering 3D models (Inventor models). It's so slow it's almost going backward. Everything was working great until this week.

Comment: can you please clarify where the models are hosted and provide a sample URN?

Comment: Here is a sample URN: dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dXhobGZmc2l3a3BvMnBidm42dWtwbmphNmp4bDRibDVwcmFpcmllX21hY2hpbmVfcHJvZHVjdGlvbi8yNTM3ODYtMS5qdA==

Comment: We’re using the object storage service

Comment: We're performing some updates, it should resolve those isolated problems.